# Is it alright to create foreign keys that are not really foreign keys in a database?

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys

I have this mock database:

**users:**

- userid

**companies:**

- company_id
- user_id

**franchises:**

- franchise_id
- company_id

**stores:**

- store_id
- franchise_id

These are all primary keys and foreign keys.

What I want to know if it is bad practice to do things like put user_id in the franchises table.

That way I can do reporting without all the relations and also in case something "gets lost" I can find out where it goes. They aren't foreign keys defined in the database but they look like foreign keys. Or should I make them foreign keys?

Thank you for your input.

edit: I also thought that denormalizing like I was thinking could possibly help speed things up, not having to use all the joins.

Comment: Foreign keys are supposed to PREVENT things from getting "lost".

Comment: You increase chances of incoherent data, with no added value.

Comment: @iDevlop How does it increase the chances of incoherent data?  It looks like it decreases it.

Comment: Wherever you add a transitive depency, you add a risk of incoherence, since modifying the user_id in one table would require changing it in another table to keep the coherence. DRY ! (Don't Repeat Yourself). I would follow TIHan's advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are talking about is a planned data denormalization.  You might be better off creating views for reporting which access the tables.  That way you don't have to alter your tables and their integrity (or store redundancy), but you can still use the associations in reporting.

Comment: @johnny: JOIN's aren't necessarily bad - if you put nonclustered indices on all the foreign key columns

Answer (score 3):

I see what you are doing. To me, what you have currently is perfectly fine; you don't need to add an extra field 'user_id' to franchise. Since a user has a relationship to a company, and a company has a relationship to a franchise; a user does have a connection to the franchise.

You may want to create a View to show everything instead of adding an extra field to a table.

Comment: Right, but if you are following normalization rules it would be redundant to store the user_id in the franchise table, besides it could lead to 'update anomalies', or so I am told.

Comment: I agree, that is what I am saying. What he has there currently, franchise does not have a user_id, but he is asking if he should add a user_id to franchise, would be bad practice.

Comment: Oh, you meant what he had was fine....as in "don't add the user_id to franchise", not the other way around.  Gotcha.